# Spinner on Item selected pass on edittext

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

I'm trying to work with the spinner. On the selected item, the item will go to the edit text. So for my interface is this:

[image]

For example, when the user click KLCC (one of the spinner item) it will go to the edit text under the Location Textview. I've tried with several options that I found on the internet, seems good, no error, but then something went wrong when I tried to insert the details, here's what it looks like after I've tried with the codes that I've tried just now:

on top of the page
[image]

[image]

and the interface keeps on. I mean there's 2 image button, 2 Name(edit text and text view) and same as the others. Before I implement the spinner all works perfectly well, until the spinner development.

(My spinner Id is = locationspinner and my edittext id is = edittext_location)

So here's the codes,

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.save, container, false);
    locationspinner = (Spinner)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.locationspinner);
    textforspinner = (EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_location);listlocation.add("Bukit Bintang");
    listlocation.add("Bukit Antarabangsa");
    listlocation.add("Brickfields");
    listlocation.add("Gombak");
    listlocation.add("Jalan Chow Kit");
    listlocation.add("Jalan Dang Wangi");
    listlocation.add("Jalan Tun Razak");
    listlocation.add("Jalan Hang Tuah");
    listlocation.add("Jalan Tunku Abdul Rahman");
    listlocation.add("KLCC");
    listlocation.add("Kampung Baru");
    listlocation.add("KL Sentral");
    listlocation.add("Lowyat");
    listlocation.add("Pavillion");
    listlocation.add("Pasar Seni");
    listlocation.add("Pudu");
    listlocation.add("Shah Alam");
    listlocation.add("Time Square");
    listlocation.add("Wangsa Maju");
    listlocation = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),R.layout.save, R.id.editText_location,listlocation);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.save);
    locationspinner.setAdapter(adp);
    locationspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            switch(arg2){
                case 0:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 0");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 3");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 4");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 5");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 6");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 7");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 8");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 9");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 10");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 11");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 12");
                    break;
                case 13:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 13");
                    break;
                case 14:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 14");
                    break;
                case 15:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 15");
                    break;
                case 16:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 16");
                    break;
                case 17:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 17");
                    break;
                case 18:
                    textforspinner.setText("Value 18");
                    break;
                default:
                    textforspinner.setText("Nothing");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });*/
    InitializeViews();
    return mRootView;
}
```

I'm really sorry for my messy question with the big picture given. I really appreciate your help and your time to help me solve my issue :)

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: InitializeViews(); for ?

Comment: That method is for insert edit text into sqlite database